# Flutter How to get all files from assets folder in one List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a bunch of xml files in assets folder, I add the path to `pubspec.yaml` and it looks like this `assets/data/somename.xml` I want to get data from it and this is how i am getting it now

```
    List filePathList = ['assets/data/widow.xml','assets/data/door.xml'];
        for(int i = 0;i<filePathList.length;i++){
          var xmlFile =  XmlDocument.parse(await rootBundle.loadString(filePathList[i]));
          checkListtemplateXmlList.add(xmlFile);
    }
```

As you can see, I am using a bad way to get data from files,
there will be many more xml files in the future. I want to find a solution to this problem, so I don't add the path in `filePathList` for every file in assets folder.
I made also a `loadData` function that load all files as I want, but my JSON files are in directory that I got by using 'getApplicationDocumentDirectory' class. There is the code:

```
    static Future<void>  loadData() async {
        final dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        List<FileSystemEntity> files = await dir.list().toList();
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          String filepath = files[i].path;
          File newFile = File(filepath);
          String name = p.basenameWithoutExtension(newFile.path);
          String myExtension = p.extension(filepath);
          if(myExtension != '.json'){
          } else{
            checkLists.add(CheckList(name));
          }
        }
        for(int i = 0;i< checkLists.length;i++){
          await checkLists[i].readFile();
        }
      }
```

how can I do something like this in `getXmlData` function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside the pubspec define only the folder:

```yaml
assets:
 - assets/data/
```

This will "load" all files inside the `data` folder.

And using this code:

```dart
// This will give a list of all files inside the `assets`.
var assets = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');
```

And use a filter to get all `xml` files.

```dart
Map json = json.decode(assets);
List get = json.keys.where((element) => element.endsWith(".xml")).toList();
```